# Possible to do a JOIN in SQL against a proprietary non-sql-server-based data source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I think this is likely possible in c# via Linq or something like that, but I'm wondering if it is possible within a SQL stored procedure.

What I'd like to, within SQL, is a join between a SQL Server table and a non-sql datasource, for example some proprietary 3rd part API like OsiSoft PI, for example.

I think provided a driver compatible with OPENROWSET is available, that would be one workable approach, but I'm wondering if there may perhaps be an alternative, more flexible approach that doesn't require that (perhaps a c# managed code stored procedure)?

Comment: What about importing data in temporary table and join that?

Comment: @user_0 Well, this is something I'll want to do on the fly, using dynamic SQL, so not an option.

Answer (score 0):

A driver compatible with OPENROWSET is OLE DB.
OLE DB provider is the mechanism to link to data sources.
Use OLE DB provider in TSQL via OPENDATASOURCE or OPENROWSET.

There are OLE DB drivers for Oracle, Access, and Excel.

Microsoft also has the OLE DB Simple Provider (OSP) Toolkit

[OLE DB Providers Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709836(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Agreed, openrowset is "a" mechanism.

Comment: So you think a custom stored procedure is a more flexible approach?  It certainly does not let you do it on the fly with using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Just wondering if there is possibly an alternative way to go about it.  Openrowset may be the only option.

Comment: This OLEDB providers article actually looks like something worth investigating though.

Comment: If this is an answer to the question then give it a check

Comment: I don't think this is an authoritatively and comprehensively correct answer - I'm beginning to think SQL CLR is the route to take.

Comment: Not authoritative nor correct?  There is a link to Microsoft.

Comment: " I'm wondering if there may perhaps be an alternative, more flexible approach that doesn't require that (perhaps a c# managed code stored procedure)?"

Comment: Why do you keep coming back to more flexible?  What could be more flexible than OPENDATASOURCE?  How do you plan to even join to this magic SP?  What is the big deal about managed code if you have to interface with an umanaged API?

Comment: "Why do you keep coming back to more flexible?"  It was literally in the question text.

Comment: Exactly - what could be more flexible than OPENDATASOURCE?

Comment: If you were familiar with it you would know writing SQLCLR code is more flexible.

Comment: I am familiar.  Flexibility is OPENROSWET versus SP in  JOIN - the stated question.  Given you can join to a OPENDATASOURCE in one line and not join to a SP at all then I would call flexible versus fail.  Where is your syntax for join to a SP?  CLR does not magically reduce this to managed code - what you have to talk to is a COM API.  Really you have a proprietary non-sql-based based data source that is managed code??  No you don't.